# Android NDK and CMake - how to use CMake to generate a Makefile which will build a third party .so using their provided .mk file

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, gstreamer

I'm trying to create an android app which uses gstreamer. I have used cerbero to build from source for android and was previously specifying static libraries in Android.mk. Then, ndk-build was generating libgstreamer_android.so for my JNI-based Android application.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native-lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native-lib.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

GSTREAMER_ROOT := /home/cerbero/build/dist/android_arm64

GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_PLAYBACK) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CODECS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_NET) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS)
G_IO_MODULES              := gnutls
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := gstreamer-video-1.0
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer-1.0.mk
```

My problem is I now want to use CMakeLists but I'm unsure how to instruct, or have CMake generate instructions for the ndk-build to generate libgstreamer_android.so. Do I need to try convert the instructions in plugins.mk and gstreamer-1.0.mk to equivalent CMake commands or can I somehow include those .mk files in my build?

Comment: Ideally you'd rewrite those old makefiles so that everything is built using CMake. That seems like the cleanest solution to me at least. There could of course be situations where that's impractical. In that case you could look into using CMake's `ExternalProject_Add` to specify a custom build command for those libraries (e.g. invoking `ndk-build` with the existing makefiles).

Comment: OK thanks - I'll look into that. I'm not sure of the practicality of rewriting the .mk files as CMakeLists as they're part of a larger third party build, but the ExternalProject_Add sounds promising